# Is there any SOIC test clip with 54 pin?

Tags: integrated-circuit, test-equipment, soic

I need to test this IC, which has 54 pins, without unplug it from the PCB.
[image]

So far I could not find SOIC test clip with 54 or more pins, so I was wondering if even such that test clip exists? If not, any other solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's ISSI's logo on that part; they make high speed chips that might not react well to being put in a socket. But you really must, there are companies that make sockets for test and burn-in applications; I know of one by the name of Loranger that will take small orders, but don't expect it to be cheap. They'll probably be one or two hundred USD and you'll have to buy at least ten of them or something.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to test? Depending on what information you're trying to gather, there's likely a way to use a bench instrument and probe a few pins at a time without a socket (and with significantly less parasitic loading, if you're using active probes).

Comment: Coming across this question again, I realize you asked for an SOIC socket, but this isn't an SOIC package. It looks more like a TSSOP to me.

Answer (score 3):

100 MHz DRAM signals might have ringing issues with inductive Socket connections.  Find other ways to debug and probe it.

Even if they did make it , it would cost more than the board is worth.